how celery flowers connect to redis throught ssh tunnel
I'm using ssh tunnel to connect to redis on remote host, but when I use ssh -L localport:target_remote_host:target_remote_port username@medium_remote_host to forwarding local request, I can connect to target remote redis by redis-cli. But when I start flower, It failed. Is there any wrong step?
And I can start flower when the target host is medium host.
